# Issues pulling info from expect script

Tags: bash, expect

So I'm pretty new at this, Lucky my scripts work, to begin with ;)
But I have a script that logs into some gear, does a few show commands, and is supposed to log out of said device.
I am trying to get it to flag at the end of the prompt with the device name, which is currently in the format of "#" but the boxes configs have a "# " randomly, and from what I gathered in a debug, it looks like it might be flagging on the wrong #, and not at the end (If this makes sense) I have something like below for code. Was wondering if anyone had any ideas on what's messed up, or what I'm doing wrong?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2KwY.jpg
I'm also not 100% on expect yet, so it's kind of horrible.

Comment: So i'm running it like
expect {

      -indices -re "# $" { 
        foreach line $expect_out(0,string) {    
          set username $line
        }
 }
 }


   
   send -- "configure terminal length 0\r"
   sleep 15
   send -- "configure info\r"
   sleep 15
   send -- "logout\r"
   interact eof
It seems to run correctly although slow, which doesn't surprise me, The boxes i'm trying to pull are slow to give you output. Not sure if there is a better way to do this?

Comment: please post your code rather than a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You want to match your prompt with:

```
expect -re {# $}
```

where the `$` means "at the end of the input string"